# Change notification image of Facebook apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if/how it's possible to change this icon when a user receives a notification through the Facebook API?

Link to nofification example: http://postimg.org/image/93lh58btd/ (I want to change the wheel icon to a custom icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon is nothing but your app's icon.

In the App Settings, open **App Details** and add **Icons** and save the changes.

[image]